# Automatically upload ProGuard mapping files to play console

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-proguard, google-play-console

Is pretty annoying to upload the ProGuard mapping files to google play console everytime i need to build a new version of my apk (my gradle build generate 4 different apks for every release so i do need to upload 4 different mapping files)

I was wondering if is possible to make this process automatically then i found this article

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/deobfuscationfiles/upload

So google does have an api to upload the mapping files, is there any gradle plugin to work with? is there any easy way to integrate?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Suggestion: If you publish an [Android App Bundle](https://g.co/androidappbundle) instead of APKs, the deobfuscation mapping file will be uploaded automatically with your artifact so you don't have to do it separately.

For the curious, the mapping file is located at `BUNDLE-METADATA/com.android.tools.build.obfuscation/proguard.map` in AAB (which is, like the APK format, just a ZIP file).

Comment: OMG this is hidden in the shadows at the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @Pierre I have an App Bundle in the Google Play Console I'm using for internal testing. When I look at Android Vitals under ANRs and Crashes it tells me where the app crash. It gives me a line number. But, when I check this line number in the app code within Android Studio it does not match. I thought the mapping file was supposed to map deobfuscated code lines with original code lines in Android Studio?

Comment: You should probably file a separate question.

Comment: Follow-up question on this: if we upload the mapping file anyway, will it ignore the one in aab file or the one that we uploaded?

Comment: Is it possible to upload the mapping file if it's already been provided in the bundle?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to upload. We do it from CI (Bitrise). And I recently found that if we upload a mapping file, Google will take that one instead of the one in the aab.

Comment: Expanding on the original answer, which links to the Overview, https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/app-bundle-format actually mentions the ProGuard mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a [gradle build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#writing_build_scripts) to run tasks after build complees
and then you can use something like this [file upload plugin](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-fileupload-plugin) to upload the file to the url

Answer (score 0):

when you have Crashlytics set up, this is being explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports#android). there's also a [Play Publisher Plugin](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) for Gradle, while it does no seem to upload the `mapping.txt`. if you want to use that API, it should be easy to extend eg. the [Google Cloud PHP Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) with another API endpoint.