# Wrong line number google play crash report

Tags: android, proguard

I have google play crash like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:109)
  at f0.k.e.b.b.a.<init> (SourceFile:1)
  at com.activities.galleryscan.ScanBarcodeFromFileActivity$b.g (SourceFile:28)
  at h0.r.o.a.a.d (SourceFile:3)
```

Here the line number `SourceFile:28` not correct why?

I was uploaded the **App Bundle** signed with proguard.

According to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458191/9868485) no need to upload mapping file to console in App Bundle

even then line number not correct why?

And I also

add this

> -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

> -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

lines in `proguard-rules.pro`

even then line number not correct why?

Comment: One stupid question: is it possible, that you look in the `SourceFile` of your current branch and not in the version, that you have uploaded and is now in play store? And if you have already published many versions of your app, not all people would have updated your app to the latest version.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing with stacktraces in Logcat when using R8. Used to work perfectly with Proguard.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting correct line numbers for Debug and incorrect ones for Release.

If your build config specified with `debuggable=false` then R8 generates incorrect line numbers.

To make it work correctly set `debuggable=true`
Eg

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: after making debuggable true for release, play store not allowing to upload app on playstore and solution for that?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? i cannot upload new release too when i set debuggable to true

Answer (score 0):

This solution Work for me

if you have multiple `proguard-rules.pro` files of modules then add

this lines in every `proguard-rules.pro` files

> -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
>
> -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

Answer (score -2):

As per Android documentation,

> After R8 obfuscates your code, understanding a stack trace is difficult (if not impossible) because names of classes and methods might have been changed. Besides renaming, R8 can also change the line numbers present in the stack traces to achieve additional size savings when writing the DEX files. Fortunately, R8 creates a mapping.txt file each time it runs, which contains the obfuscated class, method, and field names mapped to the original names. This mapping file also contains information to map the line numbers back to the original source file line numbers. R8 saves the file in the `<module-name>/build/outputs/mapping/<build-type>/` directory.

So you need to find the mapping.txt file and upload it in google play console every time a new build is pushed.

You can find more information about the same [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace) on android developer guide.

Comment: In app bundle the `mapping.txt` file already included