# Mapping files for aab in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, proguard

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458191/1635488 if we publish aab files, the mapping files will automatically be taken from there. What happens if we upload it anyway? Will it override the one from the aab file?
The place where I can upload it is here: "ReTrace mapping file"
[image: Upload mapping file]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did an experiment and can confirm that if we upload **only** `aab` file, mapping file will be taken from the `aab`. If we also upload a separate mapping file, it will override the one in the `aab`.

Comment: [Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?sjid=3250354324917712471-EU&hl=en#view_stack_traces&zippy=%2Cjava-generate-a-proguard-mapping-file) 



---`Important: This step is only required for developers using APKs. If you’re using an app bundle and Android Gradle plugin version 4.1 or later, then there's nothing you need to do. We'll automatically grab the deobfuscation file from the bundle`